# IONA ORBIX Corba::SystemException with Minor Code 12003

Tags: c++, corba, idl

I am receiving a CORBA::UNKNOWN SystemException with Minor Code: 12003 when I attempt to invoke an API defined in an IDL file that was supplied to me.

I am running IONA Orbix 3.3 and I have looked in the programming documentation for it and cannot find an associated SystemException with Minor Code 12003. Does anyone know what could be causing this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably it is an error in the server that causes this exception. Are you able to debug the server?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have been searching around and seen a couple of posts that mention that this may be the result of a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Which CORBA implementation does your server use? Have you tried a different CORBA implementation like TAOX11?

Comment: Your best bet is to submit a ticket to the support team at MicroFocus (the current owners of Orbix): http://supportline.microfocus.com/